# How to connect to Tableau Online using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, tableau-api, urlfetch

I'm looking to use the URLfetchapp service and authenticate via the Personal Access token. I'm trying to leverage the docs here:
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_authentication.htm#sign_in

So, far I could do this, which unfortunately isn't working.

```
function myFunction() {
  
var payload = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  'contentType': 'application/json',
    'credentials': {
        "personalAccessTokenName": "Tableau Token",
        "personalAccessTokenSecret": "token secret",
        "site": {
            "contentUrl": "explore"
        }

    }
}
var response =   UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.13/auth/signin",payload);
Logger.log(response)

}
```

Comment: What is a response text you got? Post it in the question text. And what is your question?

Comment: `payload` is missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` accepts two parameters in this order:

- url
- options

`options` is different from `payload`. `payload` is the request body:

```
function tableauTM() {
  /*changed name*/ const options = {
    method: 'post',
    muteHttpExceptions: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    /*added new param 'payload'*/ payload: /*added JSON.stringify*/ JSON.stringify(
      {
        credentials: {
          personalAccessTokenName: 'Tableau Token',
          personalAccessTokenSecret: 'token secret',
          site: {
            contentUrl: 'explore',
          },
        },
      }
    ),
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.13/auth/signin',
    /*changed*/ options
  );
  /*added method*/ console.log(response.getContentText());
}
```